# Where NOT in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-4, pivot-table

In Laravel we can setup relationships like so:

```
class User {
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Item');
    }
}
```

Allowing us to to get all items in a pivot table for a user:

```
Auth::user()->items();
```

However what if I want to get the opposite of that.  And get all items the user DOES NOT have yet.  So NOT in the pivot table.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: The answer below from Wallace Maxters (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27742997/2111952) would now seem to be the correct answer. Laravel now has whereDoesntHave - not sure if it did when the question was original asked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For simplicity and symmetry you could create a new method in the User model:

```
// User model
public function availableItems()
{
    $ids = \DB::table('item_user')->where('user_id', '=', $this->id)->lists('user_id');
    return \Item::whereNotIn('id', $ids)->get();
}
```

To use call:

```
Auth::user()->availableItems();
```

Comment: Actually ended up going with this solution.  The answer I posted myself doesn't work if the pivot table is empty.

Comment: Accordding to Laravel documentation, `availableItems` should be [`scopeAvailableItems`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: Indeed, question should be tagged with a version number. I believe it was v4.0 or v4.1

Comment: In Laravel 5.5+ you may swap the `->lists('user_id')` method with `->pluck('user_id)`

Answer (score 54):

Looking at the source code of the class `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, we have two methods in **Laravel** that does this: `whereDoesntHave` (opposite of  `whereHas`) and `doesntHave` (opposite of `has`)

```
// SELECT * FROM users WHERE ((SELECT count(*) FROM roles WHERE user.role_id = roles.id AND id = 1) < 1)  AND ...

    User::whereDoesntHave('Role', function ($query) use($id) {
          $query->whereId($id);
    })
    ->get();
```

this works correctly for me!

For simple "Where not exists relationship", use this:

```
User::doesntHave('Role')->get();
```

Sorry, do not understand English. I used the google translator.

Comment: Here's the link to whereDoesntHave in the API docs: http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereDoesntHave

Wallace seems to have found the best answer (perhaps it wasn't available before)

Comment: Exactly! just I found stirring in the source code (as I always do). I did not know at the time Laravel 5

Answer (score 6):

It's not that simple but usually the most efficient way is to use a subquery.

```
$items = Item::whereNotIn('id', function ($query) use ($user_id)
    {
        $query->select('item_id')
            ->table('item_user')
            ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);
    })
    ->get();
```

If this was something I did often I would add it as a scope method to the Item model.

```
class Item extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeWhereNotRelatedToUser($query, $user_id)
    {
        $query->whereNotIn('id', function ($query) use ($user_id)
        {
            $query->select('item_id')
                ->table('item_user')
                ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);
        });
    }

}
```

Then use that later like this.

```
$items = Item::whereNotRelatedToUser($user_id)->get();
```

Comment: This seems interesting, however I guess it'r running the extra query to get the list of items?

Comment: It compiles into a subquery so it's only one request to the DB. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Comment: I am using **laravel 5** and had to replace `->table` with `->from`.   Otherwise I get a *BadMethodCallException  
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()*

Answer (score 2):

How about left join?

Assuming the tables are `users`, `items` and `item_user` find all `items` not associated with the user `123`:

```
DB::table('items')->leftJoin(
    'item_user', function ($join) {
        $join->on('items.id', '=', 'item_user.item_id')
             ->where('item_user.user_id', '=', 123);
    })
    ->whereNull('item_user.item_id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you

```
$someuser = Auth::user();     

$someusers_items = $someuser->related()->lists('item_id');

$all_items = Item::all()->lists('id');

$someuser_doesnt_have_items = array_diff($all_items, $someusers_items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up writing a scope for this like so:

```
public function scopeAvail($query)
{
    return $query->join('item_user', 'items.id', '<>', 'item_user.item_id')->where('item_user.user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}
```

And then call:

```
Items::avail()->get();
```

Works for now, but a bit messy.  Would like to see something with a keyword like `not`:

```
Auth::user()->itemsNot();
```

Basically Eloquent is running the above query anyway, except with a `=` instead of a `<>`.

Comment: You should pass the $user_id into your scope rather then include the call to Auth::user() directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use:

```
DB::table('users')
        ->whereExists(function($query)
        {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                  ->from('orders')
                  ->whereRaw('orders.user_id = users.id');
        })
        ->get();
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres

Answer (score -1):

This code brings the items that have no relationship with the user.

$items = $this->item->whereDoesntHave('users')->get();

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post