# Laravel - Find groups which doesn't belong to user

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to find all groups which doesn't belong to specific user. I know how to do this with fluent but I was wondering how to find those groups using Eloquent.

This is my User model:

```
public function groups(){

return $this->belongsToMany("Group");

}
```

and this is Group model:

```
public function users(){

return $this->belongsToMany("User");

}
```

if I do: `User::find(1)->groups` I will fetch all groups which belongs to this user, but how to reverse the process, how to find groups which does **NOT** belong to this user.

Comment: already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089820/where-not-in-pivot-table

Answer (score 4):

I believe this can be done using the following:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$groups = Group::whereNotIn('id', $user->groups->modelKeys())->get();
```

So you could create a method in your User model like so:

```
public function undefinedGroups()
{
    return Group::whereNotIn('id', $this->groups->modelKeys())->get();
}
```

Then simply do:

```
User::find(1)->undefinedGroups();
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This works really well - be sure to call undefinedGroups() and not undefinedGroups (without the brackets) - your syntax will be slightly different, e.g. foreach($user->groups as $group) and foreach($user->undefinedGroups() as $group) ...