# How to fetch users not assigned to a particular role in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to fetch the users list which is not assigned to a particular role?

I have the usual DB structure & relation: `users`, `roles` & `users_roles` with `belongsToMany` relationship.

For example, `role id` for 'admin' is 1, how can I fetch users which are not assigned the role with this role id.

I tried the below query but was not successful. It gives me an error that no table was used.

```
return User::whereNotIn('roles', function($q){
    $q->where('id', 1);
})->get();
```

P.S: I do not want to check if the user is admin or not, I just want to fetch the users not assigned to a role based on role_id.

Comment: Have you made an attempt yourself yet?

Comment: Look at the `whereHas` and `whereNotHas` query builder functions.

Comment: @JasonJoslin , I have updated my question.

Comment: I got the solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089820/where-not-in-pivot-table)
Second thing, I believe I didn't do enough research. So this is a duplicate question too.